# Regular expression for strings not starting with 10

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

How can I construct a regular expression for the language over $\{0,1\}$ which is the complement of the language represented by the regular expression $10(0+1)^*$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a word doesn't start with $10$, then either it starts with some other combination of two letters, or it is shorter than two letters. All in all, we get the following regular expression for your language:
$$
\epsilon + 0 + 1 + (00+01+11)(0+1)^*.
$$

Comment: thank you so much for your helpful

Comment: I must admit I'm not very familiar with this style of regular expressions, but couldn't you say `e+1+(0+11)(0+1)*`?

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn’t fit the textual description.